# What's the point in closing subjective questions?

Tags: discussion, subjective-questions

If I have a question about tools or process that I'm unable to find out on my own, it seems obvious that sparking a subjective discussion about "one way over another" or "how do YOU store environment variables in a sinatra app?" would be helpful to the community. Especially if noobs and wannabe programmers like myself want advice.

Aside from preventing clutter and flame, what's the point?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144

Comment: Well, you spark it, but who puts out the fire? And well,"besides clutter and flame", isn't that point enough? Who wants all of this? We are not yet another forum.

Comment: Building up a corpus of duplicate targets here again is going to be a pain. sabaeus: you may find the [subjective](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=subjective) tag on http://meta.stackexchange.com interesting.

Comment: You could always use chat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I can tell, the idea is that Stack Overflow is primarily a place to get your questions *answered*. That's just what it is. Discussion is not what the system is designed for, and subjective questions tend to provoke discussion and argument, as they will almost always have subjective answers. You cannot really, definitively *answer* such a question, so it doesn't really have a place in the Stack Overflow model.

Comment: I have to disagree. Being subjective does not always mean that discussion, argument, and opinions can not be insightful.

Comment: @LoneCoder yet, most of the time devolve into one of those.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late here, but subjective questions and other questions that would generate a lot of discussion fundamentally aren't a good fit for a Q&A format.

Also keep in mind that Stack Overflow fundamentally tries to aggregate knowledge (i.e. concrete information), not just discussion or people's opinions. While extended discussion of an opinion-based question may be interesting, I'd argue that it's a lot less useful to future readers than fact-based Q&A (especially to people who are trying to solve a specific, concrete programming problems, which is the primary focus of Stack Overflow).